# MIPS data path for store word?

Tags: mips

Based on this figure, executing the SW instruction would cause these values to be assigned to the signals labeled in blue:

```
    RegWrite = 0
    ALUSrc = 1
    ALU operation = 0010
    MemRead = 0
    MemWrite = 1
    MemtoReg = X
    PCSrc =
```

However, I am a little confused which inputs will be used in the Registers block? Can anyone describe the overall SW procedure in the MIPS datapath?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution of `sw` would follow the following steps in your diagram:

1. Instruction is read and decoded from the `PC` in the Instruction Memory subcircuit.
2. The register file is read for `$rs` and `$rt` (Registers subcircuit)
3. The value of `$rs` is added to the sign extended immediate (selected by `ALUSrc`) (ALU subcircuit).
4. The added value and `$rt` are passed to the Data Memory subcircuit where the value of `$rt` is written to memory.